# Can Mac and Windows users play in the same Killing Floor game?

Tags: killing-floor

Can Mac and Windows users play together on the same Killing Floor game?

I know this is possible with a few other multi-platform steam games, but I'm not sure about this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Both the Windows version of Killing Floor and the Mac version of Killing Floor can connect to the same servers.  I own both a Windows PC and a Mac and I regularly play Killing Floor on the same servers with both of them with no issues.

Comment: This actually holds true for most Windows and Mac crossovers, so I wouldn't worry so much about it in the future.